# Magento products not showing up after import

Tags: magento-1, importexport

I've been trying to import products from Magento 1.7 to 1.9, but have been running into a lot of problems.

When trying to export with System-Import/Export-Export and then Importing through Dataflow Profiles I'm getting the error:

> Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

I tried saving with encoding UTF-8 in Sublime Text 2, but that didn't work.

When trying to export through dataflow profile and then import through dataflow profile the products don't show up, but it does finish the import without errors.

```
Processed 100% 241/241 records 
Imported 241 records
```

Here a person found a solution, but I do not really understand what he did there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953584/product-is-not-displaying-in-listing-in-magento-after-import

EDIT:
Products appear under category products and when making new product, you can select them as related product.

Comment: is it the first time you do this? or did you change something regarding flat tables for products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100 sure but I think it has something to do with the status or visibility or the product.
In the products grid, when retrieving the collection there are 2 inner joins for selecting the status and visibility. (actually there is a third one, for the name but I doubt this is the problem).
If there are no values for visibility and status the product does not appear in the grid.
To test this, edit any product in the backend, then look in the table `catalog_product_entity` for a record that does not appear in the grid.
Change the id in the url with the one from the product that does not appear and you should be able to edit it.  Set a visibility and status and save. If it appears after that int he grid then this is the problem for sure.

TO solve it, make all your products enabled and visible with this script. You can disable later the ones you don't need.

Crete a file called `fix.php` in the root of the magento instance with this code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $ids,
    array('status'=>1, 'visibility'=>4),
    0
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think that's the problem, but how do I run the script?

Comment: @Vasar. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I did that, but nothing happened, still when I look under related products of my test product I created, it shows all the products not visible individually. But the products don't show up under Catalog-Manage Products.

Comment: This means I was wrong. I had this issue before, but this is how I solved it. Maybe in your case the issue is different.

Comment: Thank you still! But is there any way to change visibility through database?

Comment: @Vasar. In theory, yes, but it's very complicated because of the EAV structure of the product tables.

Comment: Alright, I'm not going to touch that then, though all the products do show up under catalog_product_entity.

Comment: Like I said in the answer. Try to edit one in the backend, by editing any product and then change the id in the url to the one that is not shown in the grid. Save and see if it appears in the grid after that.

Comment: Well I think you were right, but I couldn't get that script working for some reason. We checked over all the products just changing the ID from address bar. Thank you.

Comment: @Marius this answer saved me hours, thanks again for all you do for our community

Comment: If you can see the products in the backend in the correct categories and doesn't show in the front end probably it is a matter of index: php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: You can run the script from shell if you have ssh access php path/fix.php or simply call the URL in browser http://yourhost.com/script/path/fix.php

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. My problem was the file encoding. Switching from `ANSI to UTF-8 resolved it`. Magento says import successful, and the query logs showed movements.

Comment: The answer is not clear please do mention where you made the change in Database or In Code? If it is in code do mention the file name.

Comment: The encoding of the CSV file has to be UTF-8

Comment: how can i change ansi to utf-8

Comment: Hi guys, using notepad ++ you can switch encoding @Rathinam

Answer (score 2):

You must have next fields in CSV

`sku   _attribute_set  _type   _category   description image   name    price   short_description   status  tax_class_id    thumbnail   visibility  weight  qty _product_websites   is_in_stock`

Please note that field **is_in_stock** is mandatory even if **qty** more than 1

Comment: I had other things done, except `is_in_stock`, this one solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new product via the backend and export it using a (newly created) Dataflow export profile. Then compare the format of this file - columns and content - to the one you are trying to import. You probably missed a required column.

You can also remove all products directly from your database:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity
```

and import the file you just exported to check if the same problems occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what would be good program to view csv files. I'm guessing just viewing it with Sublime Text isn't the right way?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in a short span of time I recommend you to create the products in your new Magento site and export it to XML or Excel format and then input your products once again in the new file and import it.

Ensure that you are not missing any columns. it hardly takes 30 minutes of your patience to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think **store id** is the main issue..you can try to setup store id using CSV or by coding you can set the store id for the product to be import..

Comment: i have one store, when i export products, _store column is empty, what can i  do ??

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the field "status" in you CSV file is set to either Enabled or Disabled.

It happened to me after I forgot to save my CSV file with all values enclosed in " ". The dataflow profiles import returned an error.  And even after I tried to feed the correct CSV later, all products have disappeared from product grid (but remained in Catalogs related product list)

The way I solved it - was to create a temporary product and fill as many fields as possible. Perform an dataflow profile export selecting "Export: All Fields"

When I got my new CSV file, I compared fields of my new product with the ones of the hidden ones.   The field "status" simply had no value. And it must be either Enabled or Disabled