# Product import successful but not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, importexport

I am testing `M2` on a `VM hosted` on my local machine.

I have successfully imported products using a `CSV` file. The products appear in the correct categories in the admin area. However, they do not appear on the front end. I `flushed the cache` and they still didn't appear. I then went in to a couple of products and saved them then flushed the cache and those products appeared.

How do I get my recently imported products to show on the front end without having to save each one and flush the cache?

Comment: try to do reindex and check once......

Comment: see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/magento-products-not-showing-up-after-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following command for reindexing:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the products showing up without the need for reindex?

Comment: yes setup up cron job

Comment: I ran but still not found in frontend

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is usual behavior in case your import file was missing column "_product_websites" with website name or 'base'. 
So opening and simply saving the product without any changes usually helps make them visible.

To attach your existing the products  to a website go to your Magento 2 back-end:

1) Products ->Catalog

2) Select products you need to update (or select all)

3)) Actions - Update attribute - Submit

4) Chose tab Websites and check the box to apply website to selected products.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the

```
Catalog -> Manage Product -> Click on Any Product
```

Then check the

Go to General tab -> Mark status to Enable
In Inventory Tab -> Mark the Stock Availability to In Stock
                    Quantity to any positive number